# Matrix Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I have worked it out and determined that both equations hold. I am wondering why this is the case. Is there a reason why the equation holds for these two types of matrices?

Comment: This is basically an application of the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: Note that the left side of the first equation factors as $(X-aI)(X-bI)(X-cI)$, and think about why the product of those three matrices is zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an application of the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

For any matrix $A$, we define its characteristic polynomial as $p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A)$. Then, $A$ satisfies $p(A) = 0$.

Example: The characteristic polynomial of the first matrix, $A$, is

$p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I-A) = \left|\begin{matrix}\lambda-a&-x&-y\\0&\lambda-b&-z\\0&0&\lambda-c\end{matrix}\right| = (\lambda-a)(\lambda-b)(\lambda-c)$ $= \lambda^3 - (a+b+c)\lambda^2+(ab+bc+ca)\lambda - abc$.

So, by the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, $A$ satisfies the equation

$A^3 - (a+b+c)A^2+(ab+bc+ca)A - abcI = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it's a really more general case which involves Exterior Algebras. In fact
$$\Delta(\lambda)=\lambda^{n}+tr(A)\lambda^{n-1}+...+tr(\Lambda^{n-1}A)\lambda+detA$$
where $tr(\Lambda^{k}A)$ can be practically thought as the sum of the principal determinants of order k.

For example:
$$
det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{1}^{1}-\lambda & a_{2}^{1} & a_{3}^{1}\\
a_{1}^{2} & a_{2}^{2}-\lambda & a_{3}^{2}\\
a_{1}^{3} & \cdots & a_{3}^{3}-\lambda
\end{array}\right)
$$
Has the following 
$$\Delta(\lambda)=\lambda^{3}(-1)+\lambda^{2}(a_{3}^{3}+a_{2}^{2}+a_{1}^{1})+\lambda(a_{2}^{1}a_{1}^{2}-a_{2}^{2}a_{1}^{1}+a_{3}^{1}a_{1}^{3}+a_{3}^{2}a_{2}^{3}-a_{3}^{3}a_{1}^{1}-a_{3}^{3}a_{2}^{2})+detA
$$
To really get an further insight on the topic we should watch for Exterior Algebra... I'm not sure about which reference to give you since the book I have where it's easily treated is in italian... but I'm sure it's plenty of english references on the subject.